# Why are my dupes tiding stuff into storage bins far away instead of nearby?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have storage bins all over my base so that when materials from digging is cleaned up it can be put into a storage bin directly available. However, dupes often ignore the closest storage bin. I've seen no effect from the currently stored amount, only that they'll ignore a storage bin that's already full. Sometimes dupes will run all around the map to put something in a storage bin that's almost full.
Edit: All my storage bins are on priority 5.

What is the algorithm for selecting which storage bin materials are stored in?
Also, is there any way to influence what storage bin materials get stored in?

Comment: Ensure your bins are configured to store the items the Dupes are transporting.

Answer (score 7):

According to this, there is a *hidden* priority hierarchy which is enabled by default (when Enable Proximity is **unchecked**). My guess that it has a queue of errands to ensure that even the most distant ones will be done. Check this box so now dupes will always choose the nearest errand if their priorities are equal.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I've rage-quit multiple times now because of how stupid dupes are and it turns out it was just this. Why is this not _always on_ by default? Why doesn't it _tell_ you about this when you get the "long commute times" warning

Answer (score 3):

First, there is a priority on storages (already mentioned by @Viv)

Second, Dupes will deliver stuff into storage closest to the dupe on a moment the job is started which is a bug (or just not an optimal algorithm) in my opinion.
So, if a dupe stands near a storage that can accept materials then this exact storage will be chosen as destination regardless of any other storage containers that are located closer to the material itself.

"Enable Proximity" has nothing to do with this behavior, it is only related to job queue itself.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The errand lives on the storage container; you can confirm by looking at the container's Errands tab. Materials also have an Errands tab, but it is always empty.

Answer (score 2):

Dupes will move stuff into storage bin that has the highest priority.  They even move stuff from one bin to another depending on the priority.

Comment: All my storage bins have priority 5.